# how to add an icon with inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

So I wrote a python program with GUI and I try to make in installer for it. How do I add an icon that appears in the start menu, task bar and desktop instead of the default one?

Here is my script for now:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Generator"
#define MyAppVersion "2.3"
#define MyAppExeName "graphics.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{E275ADFD-1486-4BBD-9121-AC28AB24F608}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Remove the following line to run in administrative install mode (install for all users.)
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\eitan piamenta.EP-PC\Documents\DIR
OutputBaseFilename=GeneratorSetup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\eitan piamenta.EP-PC\Documents\DIR\dist\graphics\icon.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\eitan piamenta.EP-PC\Documents\DIR\dist\graphics\{#MyAppExeName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\eitan piamenta.EP-PC\Documents\DIR\dist\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: thanks pal, it helped me a lot

Comment: The comment above already helped me. Thank you.